# Google Maps JavaScript API scale Polygon keep aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i drew a polygon on the map.now i want to re-size the polygon keeping the aspect ratio. i don't want to use `google.maps.Rectangle`.

[image: polygon on map]

this is my code

```
 var pointsPoly = getPoints(); 
/* */
 var ply = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#5555FF',
        paths: pointsPoly ,
        draggable:true
    });

 for (var i=0; i<pointsPoly.length; i++){
     var marker_scale = {
            map: map,
            icon: iconScale,
            flat: true,
            draggable: true,
            raiseOnDrag: false,
            position: ply.getPath().getAt(i),
            id: i
        };

        var point = new google.maps.Marker(marker_scale);
        google.maps.event.addListener(point, "drag",  
                              update_polygon_closure(ply, i));
         marker_edge[i] = point; 

    }
```

So what should I do in `update_polygon_closure()` ?

Comment: Please explain better. What do mean for scaling. you wanto draw a polygon bigger or smaller by a given ratio  or something other?

Comment: what i want to do is https://jsfiddle.net/3L140cg3/16/ , but i want to make whole polygon bigger or smaller after drag points keeping aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way to do using the ***update_polygon_closure*** method.

- Don't make the polygon editable `editable: false`.
- Make a Marker for each corner of the polygon.
- Finally, make each marker draggable and an event listener on it's "drag" event to update the polygon.

Code for creating markers and adding the event listeners:

```
for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++){
    marker_options.position = coordinates[i];
    var point = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(point, "drag", update_polygon_closure(polygon, i));
}
```

Where update_polygon_closure is defined as:

```
function update_polygon_closure(polygon, i){
    return function(event){
       polygon.getPath().setAt(i, event.latLng); 
    }
}
```

Full code for a polygon is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3L140cg3/16/). You can customize it for the rectangle.